# Assign variable as either output of equation OR nil if equation can't run (circumventing NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling, null

I'm saving an object as such:

```
@rentalrequest = RentalRequest.new do |rr|
  rr.delivery_start = Time.zone.parse(request_params[:deliverydate] + " " + request_params[:deliverytime_start]).utc
  ...
end
```

Every once in a while, my front end validation fails, and somehow, the form is posted even though `deliverydate` and `deliverytime_start` are blank. In this case, the controller breaks with a `NoMethodError` because this statement doesn't make sense:
    Time.zone.parse("")

However, rather than having to write a rescue for when this happens, I feel like it's so much easier if I can just say `rr.delivery_start = nil if Time.zone.parse doesn't work`. That way, the back end validation on the @rentalrequest object kicks in and serves as a rescue.

But I'm not sure how to write the `rr.delivery_start = nil if Time.zone.parse doesn't work` (like... if any part of it doesn't work)

Thoughts?

Comment: This issue should be solved before it reaches this piece of code. By means of [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) for example.

Comment: @IvanDenisov No, models can be edited by all sorts of things that don't go through controllers.

Comment: Thanks, to the point about strong params, I'm not sure why but I have those in place (Ivan's answer below), yet somehow things are still sneaking in. I'm sure there's an actual logical reason for this, but I can't figure it out so this is my stopgap solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking if those params exist instead?

```
@rentalrequest = RentalRequest.new do |rr|
  rr.delivery_start = nil
  if request_params[:deliverydate].present? && request_params[:deliverytime_start].present?
    rr.delivery_start = Time.zone.parse(request_params[:deliverydate] + " " + request_params[:deliverytime_start]).utc
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Hi I did this but slightly different in that I just used a ternary operator `rr.delivery_start = (request_params[:deliverydate] != "" && request_params[:deliverydate] != nil && request_params[:deliverytime_start] != "" && request_params[:deliverytime_start] != nil) ? Time.zone.parse(request_params[:deliverydate] + " " + request_params[:deliverytime_start]).utc : nil`

Comment: `present?` does a check for `!= nil && != ""` -> it's shorter :)
plus that's a hugely long ternary line... remember that code is written primarily for humans to understand, and only secondarily for computers to parse...

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is in the wrong place, your model should be maintaining its own state by itself. Something like this perhaps:

```
class RentalRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :set_delivery_start
private
  def set_delivery_start
    # Presumably validations will catch these conditions...
    return if(!deliverydate || !deliverytime_start)
    self.delivery_start = ... # whatever calculation matches the deliverydate and delivertime_start types goes here
  end
end
```

and then you'd have validations to ensure that all three delivery values made sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can `require` those parameters if `new` block is in controller.

```
def request_params
  params
    .require(:rental_request)
    .permit(..., :deliverydate, :deliverytime_start)
    .require(:deliverydate, :deliverytime_start)
end
```